# Is there a way to use a non-login user to run Rundeck jobs?

Tags: rundeck

So my goal is to create a Rundeck job that runs on a schedule and isn't run as my personal user, or any "regular" user, but rather a bot user. Ideally this bot user wouldn't have login access and restricted permissions for security reasons, but would be able to run certain jobs. I've tried searching, but the only information I'm finding is about how to create a "regular" user in Rundeck. Even if I go down that route of creating the bot user as a "regular" user, to use it, you need to pass in either the login credentials or an API token. An API token would be fine, if it could be generated and pulled in on the fly. However, that is not the case, the API has an expiration itself. If there is something I'm missing, please let me know. I'd love to get this working.

- Rundeck Version: Rundeck 3.2.1-20200113
- Rundeck Cli Version: 1.1.7

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following configuration in your `rundeck-config.properties` file (usually at `/etc/rundeck/` directory):

```
rundeck.api.tokens.duration.max=0
```

This will disable your maximum period, you can see this in the official documentation [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/config-file-reference.html#security).

With that, your "bot user" can do it through [API](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html) / [RD CLI](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/) as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Try using webhooks https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/12-webhooks.html 
You can trigger a job by making a http-request

Answer (score 0):

The way I've implemented bots is as a user who is a member of a 'bot' user group, with ACLs that lock down that group as required. Any passwords required for the scheduled job are loaded into the key storage of the bot user.

With this approach you still need someone who knows the bot credentials to login as them and set passwords/SSH keys, but that's a one-off. Is that what you're trying to avoid?

The one annoying thing I've found is that a scheduled job always seems to run as the last user to edit the job - so I grant edit access to bot users and make sure to set/reset the schedule after any edit by a normal user. Hoping to address this through https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1603, you might want to give it a .